# _.findIndex() always return -1 (lodash.js)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm working with a javascript project. I'm trying to use **lodash** tool to make life easier. I'd like to find a value in array if it exist. So, I select a **findIndex()** function. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#findIndex

It's document says that the function will

> Returns the index of the found element, else -1.

Then, I tried

```
console.log( _.findIndex([7,8,9], 7) );
```

The result is always **-1**

I think I did like the example already but I got only -1.

Please someone help.

Comment: For your usecase, `Array.indexOf` is more suited. `findIndex` is more suited to `Array<Object>`

Comment: Did you tried to use native indexOf()? It do exactly the same

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter is `[predicate=_.identity] (Function): The function invoked per iteration.` So you have to pass `expression` instead of `value`. Try like below.

```
console.log(_.findIndex([7,8,9], x => x === 7));
```

```js
console.log(_.findIndex([7,8,9], x => x === 7));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha256-VeNaFBVDhoX3H+gJ37DpT/nTuZTdjYro9yBruHjVmoQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Not compulsory. Per doc, you can do `_.findIndex(users, 'active')` and it will return all active members. Point is, yes a predicate means a function but there are various cases that are taken care of via library

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, you are absolutely correct. Library provides few more options and those are well explained in the same link that OP has posted in question. But as question contains array of `int` not `object` we need `function` to get expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use ES6 built in functions, instead of importing a library

```
const index = [7, 8, 9].findIndex(x => x === 7);

console.log(index);
```